# How to ARRAYFORMULA SUMIF that looks at each row?

Tags: google-sheets

I can't work out how to ARRAYFORMULA this formula that I have in each row of a column as it checks whether the cell in the row is in the column:

`=IF(L2=1, SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D2,C:C,C2,B:B,B2),"")`

`=IF(L3=1, SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D3,C:C,C3,B:B,B3),"")` etc.

I have tried:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT(CONCAT("L",ROW(L2:L)))=1,SUMIFS(G2:G,D2:D,INDIRECT(CONCAT("D",ROW(D2:D))),C2:C,INDIRECT(CONCAT("C",ROW(C2:C))),B2:B,INDIRECT(CONCAT("B",ROW(B2:B)))),""))` to try and check the cell on the given row against the column, but the formula isn't working for each row, only the row the formula is in.

Please could someone help?

Solved with `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L2:L=1,SUMIF(D2:D&C2:C&B2:B,D2:D&C2:C&B2:B,G2:G),""))`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L2:L=1, SUM(IF((D2:D=D2)*(C2:C=C2)*(B2:B=B2), G2:G, ), ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however the result is `=IF(L2=1, SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,D2,C:C,C2,B:B,B2),"")` for each line (so all the lines equal what row 2 should equal)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I also believe this would be simple if you shared a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L2:L=1,SUMIF(D2:D&C2:C&B2:B,D2:D&C2:C&B2:B,G2:G),""))`